# Eclipse Debug View pops up on a breakpoint in full screen mode

Tags: eclipse, debugging, view, popup

I just got Eclipse Kepler a couple of days ago - pretty nice! Unfortunately the `Debug view` gets focused while encountering a break point in full screen mode. Afterwards I need to click somewhere to make it disappear.

I made a screen shot:

[image]

Can this be customized? I wasn't able to find anything in the preferences. I also had the same issue with the `Console view` but these two nice buttons made it work. [image]
 Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you can resize it to smaller, so it won't be that annoying. This is Juno, but hopefully works with Kepler: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-layout_breadcrumb_auto_expand.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can disable using a setting, from eclipse  Window-> Preferences -> Run/Debug -> uncheck Activate the debug view when a breakpoint is hit.

[image]